# breakup row into 2 rows, pulling specific cells into each row

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I need to copy each row into 2 rows with certain columns from the orignal row separated into row 1 and row 2, using excel vba. What I need is demonstrated below:

Input data:
**Contract___VIN#____Interest$___Principal$**
contract1___1234____$20________$400
contract2___abcd____$40________$600

Desired output:
**Contract___VIN#____Amount$**
contract1___1234____$20
contract1___1234____$400
contract2___abcd____$40
contract2___abcd____$600

I'm struggling with the concept of how to precisely navigate through rows and columns of ranges... I'm thinking this will be a for loop?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you want a new sheet with the updated info (which would be a lot easier and faster), or are you wanting the current sheet modified ??

Comment: I want it in a new sheet!  Thanks for your time, i do appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Study this code by stepping through each line, using <kbd>F8</kbd>

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set newWs = .Add(After:=Worksheets(.Count))         'Add a new ws
        newWs.Name = Format(Now, "yyyy-mmm-dd hh-mm-ss")    'Rename it
    End With

    newWs.Range("A1:C1") = Split("Contract VIN# Amount$")   'Add headers to the new ws

    Dim colA As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange        'Get UsedRange in colA (Sheet1)
        Set colA = .Columns("A").Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    End With

    Dim itm As Range, oldRow As Long, newRow As Long
    oldRow = 1

    For Each itm In colA.Cells
        oldRow = oldRow + 1     'increment row on old sheet (Sheet1)
        newRow = newRow + 2     'increment row on new sheet (double)
        With newWs
            .Cells(newRow, "A") = Sheet1.Cells(oldRow, "A")     'row1new(A) = row1old(A)
            .Cells(newRow, "B") = Sheet1.Cells(oldRow, "B")     'row1new(B) = row1old(B)
            .Cells(newRow, "C") = Sheet1.Cells(oldRow, "C")     'row1new(C) = row1old(C)
            .Cells(newRow + 1, "A") = Sheet1.Cells(oldRow, "A") 'row2new(A) = row1old(A)
            .Cells(newRow + 1, "B") = Sheet1.Cells(oldRow, "B") 'row2new(B) = row1old(B)
            .Cells(newRow + 1, "C") = Sheet1.Cells(oldRow, "D") 'row2new(C) = row1old(D)
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```